# How to get apk file

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I need a .apk file :  https://play.google.com/store/apps its a free version that I need to plug in to the emulator,  but need the root file if you have a handy way of getting this.

Please guide how to get .apk file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install the Free APK from `Google Play Store` on your device and then download [**Airdroid**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)
from `Google Play Store` and then connect your device to your PC by following the steps provided in Airdroid then click on `Apps` it will show the list of installed application then you can click on Download to get the `APK` file of the installed application.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get the .apk file from an app in the Google Play store. You will only get the app itself.
The only way to get that .apk from an app is, by setting up a dev environment using Eclipse or NetBeans. And in that case you can find the apk file in the bin folder within your project directory.

Comment: dev enviroment on Eclipse? How I get this app on PC to get its .apk file? I install it on mobile. Is there is any way to install this app on Eclipse emulator?

Answer (score 0):

If you wont to plug in to the emulator  Google Play App (run android app on PC) just use [BlueStack](http://www.bluestacks.com/).